# Why don't I appear in the Stack Overflow ranking?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, rankings

I have a reputation of over 300 on Stack Overflow. I was searching my name in the Stack Overflow ranking ([link](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)) to look up my position. But it doesn't appear.

#### Question:

Is there another condition that I must meet to be in the ranking?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, but it's not a duplicate question either, you did not have to rate me negative. It was unnecesary. I only was triying to delete your unncesary "duplicate". But of course, you are the "expert".

Comment: Until proven otherwise, this is duplicate. If tomorrow (after the night recalculation Robert mentioned) you'll still not be displayed in the Leagues then please update and by all means, I'll put the [tag:bug] tag back and reopen. But I'm pretty sure that won't happen.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2017-11-01/7888588#7888588 looks like you're there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have at least [200 rep to be in the leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). If you look on the rankings page you'll find the following text:

> users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

Rankings are recalculated nightly and you gained 130 rep today so last night you had 301 - 130 rep, which was less than 200.

Try again tomorrow.

In fact you're findable now since I've updated this answer one day later.

Comment: I`ll do. If true, I'll give your answer as good tomorrow, thanks Robert!